# Newcomer's Rhyming Riddle - What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> To start a creature, black and white;
>   In myth, I may give you a fright.
>   I may be found on top a flame;
>   Eternal youth when I'm a name.
>   5 rings, but only in the West;
>   Reversed, I give a little rest.
>   A box or jewel in your ear;
>   To beg for coins from strangers near.
>   Connecting bodies that are wet;
>   Add a letter, I'll heave and sweat.

**What am I?**

Comment: Great first puzzle. Good clues and excellent meter in the poem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> **PAN**.

---

To start a creature, black and white;

> A PANDA is a black and white creature.

In myth, I may give you a fright.

> PAN was a Greek god whose appearance caused terror. He lends his name to the word *panic*.

I may be found on top a flame;

> A PAN is a cooking utensil, often found on stovetops.

Eternal youth when I'm a name.

> PETER PAN never grows up.

5 rings, but only in the West;

> OP revealed the intended answer is the PAN AMERICAN GAMES, which resemble the Olympics, except that only countries from North and South America compete.

Reversed, I give a little rest.

> A NAP is a short rest. (*This was my inroad to the solution.*)

A box or jewel in your ear;

> PANDORA'S BOX is a famous artifact from mythology; PANDORA is a popular music streaming site; PANDORA is also a brand of jewelry.

To beg for coins from strangers near.

> To PANHANDLE is to beg for money in the street.

Connecting bodies that are wet;

> The PANAMA CANAL connects the Atlantic Ocean with the Pacific Ocean.

Add a letter, I'll heave and sweat.

> To PANT is to breathe heavily, often while heaving and sweating.

Comment: Nice! I'll leave you to explain the remaining lines.

Comment: "5 rings, but only in the West" refers to the Pan Am Games, as they are similar to the Olympics but only the Americas compete. May have been a stretch for a clue on my half.